# merging dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

Sorry for the very general title but I'll try to be as specific as possible.

I am working on a text mining application. I have a large number of key value pairs of the form ((word, corpus) -> occurence_count) (everything is an integer) which I am storing in multiple python dictionaries (tuple->int). These values are spread across multiple files on the disk (I pickled them). To make any sense of the data, I need to aggregate these dictionaries Basically, I need to figure out a way to find all the occurrences of a particular key in all the dictionaries, and add them up to get a total count.

If I load more than one dictionary at a time, I run out of memory, which is the reason I had to split them in the first place. When I tried , I ran into performance issues. I am currently trying to store the values in a DB (mysql), processing multiple dictionaries at a time, since mysql provides row level locking, which is both good (since it means I can parallelize this operation) and bad (since it slows down the insert queries)

What are my options here? Is it a good idea to write a partially disk based dictionary so I can process the dicts one at a time? With an LRU replacement strategy? Is there something that I am completely oblivious to?

Thanks!

Comment: Define "large number".  "I run out of memory".  Really?  Without details like number of elements in the dictionary, I find this hard to understand.  "When I tried , I ran into performance issues".  Tried what?

Comment: When you say "everything is an integer", do you mean that the word and corpus are integer ids of a word and a corpus? Are the word ids consistent across corpora?

Comment: thanks everyone! I redefined the problem a little bit to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

A disk-based dictionary-like exists -- see the [shelve](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html?highlight=shelve#module-shelve) module.  Keys into a shelf must be strings, but you could simply use `str` on your tuples to obtain equivalent string keys; plus, I read your Q as meaning that you want only `word` as the key, so that's even easier (either `str` -- or, for vocabularies < 4GB, a struct.pack -- will be fine).

A good relational engine (especially PostgreSQL) would serve you well, but processing one dictionary at a time to aggregate each word occurrences over all corpora into a `shelf` object should also be OK (not quite as fast, but simpler to code, since a `shelf` is so similar to a `dict` except for the type constraint on keys [[and a caveat for mutable values, but as your values are `int`s that need not concern you).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, if I understand your question correctly

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pickle

result = defaultdict(int)
for fn in filenames:
    data_dict = pickle.load(open(fn))
    for k,count in data_dict.items():
        word,corpus = k
        result[k]+=count
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If I understood your question correctly and you have integer ids for the words and corpora, then you can gain some performance by switching from a dict to a list, or even better, a numpy array. This may be annoying!

   Basically, you need to replace the tuple with a single integer, which we can call the newid. You want all the newids to correspond to a word,corpus pair, so I would count the words in each corpus, and then have, for each corpus, a starting newid. The newid of (word,corpus) will then be word + start_newid[corpus].

   If I misunderstood you and you don't have such ids, then I think this advice might still be useful, but you will have to manipulate your data to get it into the tuple of ints format.
2. Another thing you could try is rechunking the data.

   Let's say that you can only hold 1.1 of these monsters in memory. Then, you can load one, and create a smaller dict or array that only corresponds to the first 10% of (word,corpus) pairs. You can scan through the loaded dict, and deal with any of the ones that are in the first 10%. When you are done, you can write the result back to disk, and do another pass for the second 10%. This will require 10 passes, but that might be OK for you.

   If you chose your previous chunking based on what would fit in memory, then you will have to arbitrarily break your old dicts in half so that you can hold one in memory while also holding the result dict/array.